# Providing counter examples for a false statement

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

1) Let f : A -> B be a function so that there is a function g : B -> A so that g o f = idA. Then f is surjective.

2) Let f : A -> B be a function so that there is a function g : B -> A so that f o g = idB. Then f is injective.

What are the possible counterexamples for these 2 false statements?

Comment: Any thoughts?  Hint:  try very simple sets.  For the first statement, say, suppose $A$ has one element, and $B$ has two.

Answer (score 0):

Try if these examples work:

i) $f(x):=x:[0,+\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ and  $g(x):=|x|:\mathbb{R}\to [0,+\infty)$.

ii) $f(x):=|x|:\mathbb{R}\to [0,+\infty)$ and  $g(x):=x:[0,+\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** For the first, take $A = \{1\}$ and $B = \{1,2\}$.  For the second, take $A = \{1,2\}$ and $B = \{1\}$.

Comment: then how do we derive at the composites?

Comment: @LarryYeo go through some trial and error; you don't have a lot of choices here.